# Unity Shader Graph, set blackboard properties from code

Tags: unity, shaders

I have a Shader Graph shader with a blackboard property that I want to change from within my code. The property is called `Highlight` here are the things I have tried:

```
Color myColor = new Color(1f,0,0,1f);
material.Color = myColor;                       // throws error (as I expected)
material.SetVector("Highlight", myColor);       // Name in blackboard window
material.SetVector("HighlightColour", myColor); // Name in material property
material.SetVector("Color_8C3A526", myColor);   // Name in the shader inspector
```

None of these work.

Here's the shader set up:
[image: The Unity Shader Graph showing a fresnel shader with a Highlight property in the blackboard]

Answer (score 2):

[In Unity 2018.2, they've added an editable Reference Name for properties in shader graphs](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/07/10/2018-2-is-now-available/#property), letting you replace these unfriendly generated names like `Color_8C3A5256` with semantically meaningful names.

> You can now edit the Reference name for a property, making it far easier to reference your shader properties from script. To do so, select the property and type a new name next to Reference. If you want to reset to the default name, right-click Reference, and select, Reset reference.
>
> In the expanded Property window, you can now also toggle the Exposed checkbox.
>
> [image: Screenshot of property editing window with reference name field selected.]

Answer (score 1):

To set the colour in the Shader use:

```
Color myColor = new Color(1f,0,0,1f);
material.SetColor("Color_8C3A526", myColor);
```

Although the blackboard parameter color is "Highlight", it has a unique codename that you can find by opening the inspector and selecting (but not opening) your shader graph. The shader in the question looks like this:

[image]

The Highlight colour appears under Properties and has the unique key of `Color_8C3A526`. If you change the name of Highlight in the shader graph tool then the unique key will remain the same.

Thank you to @DMGregory, who got me most of the way there.