# In Unity's Shader Graph how do you access parameters from code?

Tags: unity, shaders

I recently rewrote a shared I was using into Shader Graph. As an example I carried out the color as an external parameter.

In my traditional shader to set the color I would call something like

```
MyMaterial.SetColor("_NewColor", color)
```

In the new code, I could not figure out the name of the parameter until I looked at the generated code. Turns out my Color parameter was actually named "Color_D027E98" So now my code is

```
MyMaterial.SetColor("Color_D027E98", color);
```

Not very pretty and I don't know how constant D027E98 is. Is this the correct way of changing a shader's parameter? Should I be doing something different using Shader Graph - Is this number going to change on me as if I update my shader?

Comment: Based on this question, Shader Graph makes me sad. Shader Forge at least let you name nodes intelligently so that you *actually knew what they were* for precisely this purpose.

Comment: @Draco18s I am guessing shader forge won't work with the new pipeline, this is the future. Also shader forge did not seem to work for me

Comment: From the title this looked like a duplicate of [Unity Shader Graph, set blackboard properties from code](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/158898/unity-shader-graph-set-blackboard-properties-from-code), but from your description it sounds like you're actually asking "How to control names assigned to parameters in a shader graph" or something similar. Is that accurate?

Comment: @DMGregory I did miss that question. I does at least answer my question to the fact that the name is persistent., What I am really asking is what is the right way of working with it. Having the weird code name that you have to get out of source  feels very ugly